# How to define constants or environment variables in Magento 2.2.6?

Tags: magento2, php, global-variable

I want to define constants to use in all my project. How to define constant or environment variables to access all over the project without any special declaration ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the constant with `const` keyword as :

```
const PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY = 'trans_email/ident_sales';
```

To call constant in the same file use : `self::PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY`

To call the same constant in another file use : `VendorName\ModuleName\Controller\FileName::PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY`

Comment: I don't want to call by refference, I just want to call directly as we call in codeigniter or in other frameworks like 
echo PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY;